# How to carry on after reaching an exception?

Tags: java

My code is designed to loop through a file, adding as it goes then displaying a total. At the moment, it handles errors correctly however the moment it hits incorrect data (non-integer) it just gives the total up until that line of the text file. What I want is for it to carry on past that as the data ahead may still be integer. How can I do this? Not only that, but my catch for InputMismatchException is not displaying the appropiate error.

my code:

```
public class HandlingTheException {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    int integerTotal = 0;
    int i;
    Scanner scan = null;
    File integerFile = new File ("someintegers.txt");

    try {
        scan = new Scanner (integerFile);
        System.out.println("File contents: " );

        while (scan.hasNextInt()) {
            i = scan.nextInt();
            integerTotal += i;
            System.out.println(i);
        }

        System.out.println("File total: " + integerTotal + ". ");
        System.out.println("Finished. ");
        scan.close();
    }
    catch (InputMismatchException e1) {
        System.err.println("Incorrect data type within file. Use integer only." );
    }
    catch (FileNotFoundException e2) {
        System.err.println(integerFile.getName()+" does not exist");
    }
}
```

An example of the file:
10
20
30
40
50
sixty <--- when it hits this line the program will stop. It gives the total up until this point but it could go on to include 70,80,90,100.... How?
70
80
90
100

Answer (score 0):

Put the error causing code inside a try/catch block and eat the exception after proper logging.

```
while (scan.hasNextInt()) {
        try {
            i = scan.nextInt();
        } catch (Exception e) {
             i =0;
            //logging if necessary
        }
        integerTotal += i;
        System.out.println(i);
    }
```

instead of `Exception` you can catch more specific `NumberFormatException`